# How to add "AddThis" button to Joomla

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, addthis

I have added the *[AddThis for Joomla!](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381232-addthis-for-joomla-#.UTChOqWqf-Q)* module to Joomla. The problem is that I cannot make it floating to the left. For example This site has *AddThis* button on the left and it remains in the same place while scrolling. I want it exactly like this in my Joomla site. In the module manger of the *AddThis* in Joomla there is no option to do it.

Can anyone help in this matter?

Comment: are you referring to the "Share" button that appear on their site in the bottom right hand corner?

Answer (score 0):

To make something fixed on the left hand side of the page, open the CSS file and replace the following at the bottom of the file:

```
.joomla_add_this {
    float:left;
}
```

with this:

```
.joomla_add_this {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 100px;
}
```

You can change `top: 0;` which defines how far from the top the module will be. If you want to have it fixed at the bottom, then use `bottom: 0;` instead.

Hope this helps